# R Markdown simple interactivity

Tags: r, shiny, markdown, knitr, r-markdown

I would like to create an actual HTML report in markdown in which the users can subset by a controlling dropdown to customize the report. I want the final report to be **knit(R)ed** as opposed to rendered as a shiny application, so I don't want an rmd file. I actually want an html file.

[image]

````
---
title: "Testing"
author: "Doe"
date: "September 1, 2017"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

This R Markdown document is made interactive using Shiny. Unlike the more traditional workflow of creating static reports, you can now create documents that allow your readers to change the assumptions underlying your analysis and see the results immediately. 

To learn more, see [Interactive Documents](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_shiny.html).

## Inputs and Outputs

You can embed Shiny inputs and outputs in your document. Outputs are automatically updated whenever inputs change.  This demonstrates how a standard R plot can be made interactive by wrapping it in the Shiny `renderPlot` function. The `selectInput` and `sliderInput` functions create the input widgets used to drive the plot.

    ```{r eruptions, echo=FALSE}
    inputPanel(
      selectInput("n_breaks", label = "Number of bins:",
                  choices = c(10, 20, 35, 50), selected = 20),

      sliderInput("bw_adjust", label = "Bandwidth adjustment:",
                  min = 0.2, max = 2, value = 1, step = 0.2)
    )

    renderPlot({
      hist(faithful$eruptions, probability = TRUE, breaks = as.numeric(input$n_breaks),
           xlab = "Duration (minutes)", main = "Geyser eruption duration")

      dens <- density(faithful$eruptions, adjust = input$bw_adjust)
      lines(dens, col = "blue")
    })
    ```
````

Comment: The RStudio folks are very clear that Shiny apps can't be standalone HTML.  If you're comfortable writing an `htmlwidget` you could put user controls into the widget and render a standalone HTML doc that way.